# What is the wildcard character for matching values in list?

Tags: c#

What is the wildcard character use for matching string in list array?

```
var myList = new List<string>();

myList.Add("0000-0000-0001/111_Age_3_20150518T0800-0400.txt");
myList.Add("0000-0000-0002/222_Bal_3_20120518T0800-0400.txt");
myList.Add("0000-0000-0003/333_DDS_3_20140518T0800-0400.txt");

var filteredFiles = myList.Where(x => x.EndsWith("*_20150518T*-*.txt")).ToList();
```

I tried wildcard and ampersand but they both don't work.

I'm hoping this would work in `x.EndsWith("*_*_*_20150518T*-*.txt")` .

Comment: You need to use [RegEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do that. `String.EndsWith` doesn't support them.

Comment: That's suck!   Why do I see examples like this in Google search result?

Comment: @fletchsod did you try with x.EndsWith(".txt") without the asterisk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use regex for complicated match scenarios within the where clause:

```
myList.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, @"{Regex Pattern}")).ToList();
```

For [EndsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only accepts string literals.

---

Actual pattern with data in a unit test per OPs request:

```
string data = "0000-0000-0001/111_Age_3_20150518T0800-0400.txt";

Console.WriteLine (Regex.IsMatch(data, @"20150518T[^.]+\.txt")); // True
```

---

IMHO - Regex

Regex patterns in their base form are simply *literal* text to find.

If one writes a pattern against *which what is known,* instead of unknown, it makes matching a lot easier.

I crafted the pattern to anchor off of `20150518T` and then I knew the next known as a literal period `.`. So I crafted the unknown with the known as `[^.]+` which says, eat up (match) anything that is NOT `^` a literal period `.`, one or more (the `+`).

So learn a few basics of regex pattern matching, apply my above philosophy with a second one to avoid wild cards when possible (the ambigous `.*`), and one finds they can effectively regex pattern matching in their day to day coding. IMHO

Comment: What the wildcard would be after the "T" and before the "-" ?  Did you run the script?  I dont know how to use pattern formula.

Comment: @fletchsod I updated the answer to not look for a `-`, one of your edits I copied had a dash, I thought it was a literal, it was not.

Comment: That works great now!  Thanks.  Wish I don't have to use RegEx.  Oh well.

Comment: @fletchsod see my final update. Don't avoid regex, learn the basics of pattern matching and take it to any language. HTH

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on Array.findAll():

```
List<string> filteredFiles=myList.FindAll(delegate(string s) { return myRegex.IsMatch(s);});
```

If you are not familiar with Regex, use this function to convert a pattern using Wildcards to Regex.

```
public string WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
{             
    string result= Regex.Escape(pattern).Replace(@"\*", ".+?").Replace(@"\?", "."); 
    if (result.EndsWith(".+?")) result = result.Remove(result.Length - 3,3)+".*";
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple

```
var filteredFiles = myList.Where(x => x.EndsWith(".txt"));
```